Is the sequence $a_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!} \int_0^{n-k+1} x^k e^{-x} dx$ bounded?
Let
$$
a_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!} \int_0^{n-k+1} x^k e^{-x} dx
$$
for all $n \ge 0$.

Is the sequence $(a_n)_{n \ge 0}$ bounded?

The integral $\int_0^{n-k+1} x^k e^{-x} dx$ is the lower incomplete gamma function, which converges to $k!$ as $n \to \infty$. Hence, we trivially have
$$
a_n \le \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!} \cdot k! = n,
$$
but the right-hand side is unbounded. Is it possible to obtain a better estimate?

show that restricting the integral to $x \in [k-1,k]$ (where the integrand is big as the maximum is attained at $x=k$ so the integral on $[k-1,k]$ is about $k^ke^{-k}$) the corresponding term is $>> k^{-1/2}$ and since $n-k+1 \ge k$ for $2k \le n$ say we have that $a_n >> \sum_{k=1}^{n/2}k^{-1/2} \to \infty$

In fact, as $n\to\infty$, we have $\color{blue}{a_n=n/2+5/8+O(r^{-n})}$, where $\color{blue}{r\approx 4.6278487254395}$ is the smallest possible value of $|z|$ for a solution $z\in\mathbb{C}$, $z\neq 1$ of the equation $z=e^{1-z}$. To get this, use
$$
\frac1{k!}\int_0^y x^k e^{-x}\,dx=1-e^{-y}\sum_{j=0}^k\frac{y^j}{j!}=e^{-y}\sum_{j=k+1}^\infty\frac{y^j}{j!}
$$
first, so that $a_n=\sum_{k=0}^n e^{-(n-k+1)}\sum_{j=k+1}^\infty(n-k+1)^j/j!$, and consider
\begin{align}
g(z):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{j=k+1}^\infty z^n e^{-(n-k+1)}(n-k+1)^j/j!
\\\color{gray}{\text{[switch summations]}}\quad
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{n=k}^\infty\sum_{j=k+1}^\infty z^n e^{-(n-k+1)}(n-k+1)^j/j!
\\\color{gray}{\text{[replace $n$ with $n+k$]}}\quad
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{j=k+1}^\infty z^{n+k}e^{-(n+1)}(n+1)^j/j!
\\\color{gray}{\text{[switch summations]}}\quad
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^{j-1} z^{n+k}e^{-(n+1)}(n+1)^j/j!
\\\color{gray}{\text{[sum over $k$]}}\quad
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^\infty z^n\frac{1-z^j}{1-z}e^{-(n+1)}(n+1)^j/j!
\\\color{gray}{\text{[sum over $j$]}}\quad
&=\frac1{1-z}\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n(1-e^{(n+1)(z-1)})
\\\color{gray}{\text{[sum over $n$]}}\quad
&=\frac1{1-z}\left(\frac1{1-z}-\frac1{e^{1-z}-z}\right)
\end{align}
defined initially for $|z|<1$. Computing residues, we see that the function
$$
\Delta(z):=g(z)-\frac1{2(1-z)^2}-\frac1{8(1-z)}
$$
is analytic at $z=1$ (hence in $|z|<r$ with $r$ given above). Thus the series
$$
\Delta(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(a_n-\frac n2-\frac 58\right)z^n
$$
converges if $|z|<r$. And the roots of $z=e^{1-z}$ are simple, so $\Delta(z)$ has simple poles there, which justifies the fact that the coefficients of the above expansion of $\Delta(z)$ are $O(r^{-n})$.

Very nice approach !

Interesting is to notice that $$\log \left(\left| a_n- \left(\frac{n}{2}+\frac{5}{8}\right)\right| \right)\sim -(4.47+1.54,n)$$ with $R^2=0.991$ which is almost parallel to $\log(r^{-n})$

Too long for a comment
@Conrad already showed in comments that the sequence
$$a_n=\sum _{k=0}^n \left(1-\frac{\Gamma
   (k+1,n-k+1)}{\Gamma (k+1)}\right)$$ is unbounded.
Using asymptotics, you could show that
$$\frac n 2<a_n < \frac n2+1$$ and empirically that
$$a_n \sim \frac n2+\frac 58$$ already given rigourously by @metamorphy while I was typing.
